# Can you put i3 on an alternate GUI terminal?

Tags: gui, i3-wm

Is there a way to put another GUI type, such as [i3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_%28window_manager%29), on one of the other GUI terminals (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>)?

Comment: Yes there is. Can you please rephrase your question, so that your actual motivation becomes clear? It may also help to clarify, that i3 is a window manager (I had to google that first), and whether you want it to appear directly on that virtual terminal or behind a display manager.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more info like: what version of Ubuntu you're running...   What you're trying to accomplish, what you've done already... The comment above is longer (and clearer) then your one-line question.  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to run another x server.

As I recall, you can't do this with the standard login managers (lightdm, gdm), because they're designed on the assumption that only once instance of them will be running. However, I've done it with wdm, although it's a bit clunky.

You probably want to look into running your second server manually via startx.